# Changing input for the Google Map API

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google Map API in my GAE app but having trouble making it the way i want it to be. Im trying to use the code examples from gecoding-simple 
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

I'm trying to display the map of where my event take place which is from

```
class Event(db.Model):
   title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
   description = db.TextProperty()
   time = db.DateTimeProperty()
   location = db.PostalAddressProperty()
   creator = db.UserProperty()
   edit_link = db.TextProperty()
   gcal_event_link = db.TextProperty()
   gcal_event_xml = db.TextProperty()
   hobby = db.ReferenceProperty(Hobby)
```

Instead of having the text field and type where the marker would be, I would like to put the marker from Event.location

```
var address = {{event.location}};
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
```

i've changed var address = document.getElementById("address").value to {{event.location}}
thought thats what i have to do... but it doesnt work...

How do i do that... where do i have to change the example code.

event is created in the following class.

```
class CreateEvent(BasePage):
title = 'Create!'

def get(self):
  """Show the event creation form"""
  self.write_page_header()
  template_values = {}
  path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
  path = os.path.join(path, 'create.html')
  self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  self.write_page_footer()

def post(self):
  """Create an event and store it in the datastore.

  This event does not exist in Google Calendar. The event creator can add it
  to Google Calendar on the 'events' page.
  """
  self.write_page_header()


if self.request.get("hobby"):
  hobby_name = self.request.get('hobby')
  new_hobby = Hobby(name=hobby_name.strip(), key_name = hobby_name.strip())

# Create an event in the datastore.
new_event = Event(title=self.request.get('name'),
                  creator=users.get_current_user(),
                  # Take the time string passing in by JavaScript in the
                  # form and convert to a datetime object.
                  time=datetime.datetime.strptime(
                      self.request.get('datetimestamp'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'),
                  description=self.request.get('description'),
                  location=self.request.get('location'),
                  hobby = new_hobby)
new_event.put()
```

info.html is the following

```
<h1 id="header">Event Info</h1>
<p>Name: {{event.title|escape}}</p>
<p>Description: {{event.description|escape}}</p>
<p>Location: {{event.location|escape}}</p>
<p>Attendee: {{event.attendee.email|escape}}</p>
<p>When: {{event.time}} (UTC)</p>

{% for greeting in greetings %}
  {% if greeting.author %}
    <b>{{ greeting.author.nickname }}</b> wrote:
  {% else %}
   An anonymous person wrote:
  {% endif %}
  <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
{% endfor %}



<form action="/sign" method="post">
  <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Write on the Wall"></div>
</form>


google map API follows here.
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Just to make it sure. Did you debug through your code? Is there a value inside your event.location? What is the value inside your location? Is it a street, a city or a latlng?

Comment: The Value inside event.location is a city.  Which the app ask for it when it makes the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var address = 'London';
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status)
```

Seems to be working fine at my side.
Do you get any errors?

Why is your event.location framed with double brackets?
Maybe thats causeing the Problem?

Comment: When I type in the city in var address= field it does work too.  the double brackets were my mistake, my bad.  however, now i get ZERO RESULT, so i guess it means there is nothing in event.location, but when i check in my table there is.. so... idk what to do

Comment: Could you give me an example where you extract you city from?

Comment: thank you for your help halbherz,  I have edited the entry in include the code

Comment: Iam not sure, because iam not so familiar with the app-engine, but doesn't the `self.request.get` search for a dom element with this name as an attribute? So i suppose you have an dom elemnt with the city in it?